# How to separate a string of character and read it in R as a vector?

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a database with a column that contains species name in a string of characters:

```
plant.first.id$sp.lst[42]
```

Returns:

```
[1] ['Trema lamarckianum', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Trema micranthum', 'Cannabis sativa']
```

I'd like to take the whole column of `plant.first.id$sp.lst` and turn the values into a vector that I'll be able to manipulate.

For example, I want this:

```
> plant.first.id$sp.lst[3:5]
[1] []                                                                                                                                                        
[2] ['Ficus carica', 'Aphananthe philippinensis', 'Ficus insipida', 'Aphananthe monoica', 'Castilla elastica', 'Maclura cochinchinensis', 'Maclura fruticosa']
[3] ['Artocarpus tamaran']                                                                                                                                    

dput(plant.first.id$sp.lst[3:5])
structure(c(14L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("['Artocarpus tamaran']", 
"['Artocarpus thailandicus']", "['Boronia algida', 'Zanthoxylum coreanum', 'Citrus reticulata']", 
"['Cissus integrifolia', 'Cissus populnea', 'Cissus hastata', 'Cissus trianae', 'Cissus penninervis', 'Cissus assamica']", 
"['Cryptandra amara', 'Broussonetia papyrifera', 'Serichonus gracilipes', 'Colubrina asiatica', 'Artocarpus tamaran', 'Artocarpus chama', 'Artocarpus thailandicus', 'Artocarpus rubrovenius', 'Gouania mauritiana']", 
"['Enterolobium gummiferum']", "['Ficus carica', 'Aphananthe philippinensis', 'Ficus insipida', 'Aphananthe monoica', 'Castilla elastica', 'Maclura cochinchinensis', 'Maclura fruticosa']", 
"['Maclura cochinchinensis']", "['Pouteria multiflora', 'Diospyros toposia', 'Van-royena castanosperma', 'Micropholis guyanensis', 'Pycnandra comptonii', 'Chrysophyllum venezuelanense']", 
"['Pouteria multiflora', 'Van-royena castanosperma', 'Chrysophyllum venezuelanense', 'Pycnandra comptonii', 'Micropholis guyanensis']", 
"['Trema lamarckianum', 'Cannabis sativa', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Ficus annulata', 'Trema micranthum', 'Celtis iguanaea', 'Artocarpus thailandicus']", 
"['Trema lamarckianum', 'Ficus annulata', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Trema micranthum', 'Cannabis sativa']", 
"['Trema lamarckianum', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Trema micranthum', 'Cannabis sativa']", 
"[]"), class = "factor")
```

To be something like:

```
c("")
c('Ficus carica', 'Aphananthe philippinensis', 'Ficus insipida', 'Aphananthe monoica', 'Castilla elastica', 'Maclura cochinchinensis', 'Maclura fruticosa')
c('Artocarpus tamaran')
```

in a list form.

I've tried this:

```
strsplit(as.vector(plant.first.id$sp.lst[42]),split = ",")
```

But it's not usable:

```
[[1]]
[1] "['Trema lamarckianum'" " 'Parasponia rigida'"  " 'Trema tomentosum'"   " 'Trema micranthum'"   " 'Cannabis sativa']"
```

Also this:

```
gsub("[[(]", "(", plant.first.id$sp.lst[[42]])
gsub("]", ")", plant.first.id$sp.lst[[42]])
```

But still not very helpful...

```
[1] "('Trema lamarckianum', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Trema micranthum', 'Cannabis sativa']"
[1] "['Trema lamarckianum', 'Parasponia rigida', 'Trema tomentosum', 'Trema micranthum', 'Cannabis sativa')"
```

Comment: I think your problem is that `strsplit()` returns a list. Check if `strsplit(as.vector(plant.first.id$sp.lst[42]),split = ",")[[1]]` works for you

Comment: What is the output of `str(plant.first.id$sp.lst[42])`? These square brackets look kind of weird...EDIT: I think you need to remove the square brackets and then do a strsplit. Or try to fix the read from the data base.

Comment: The output of `str(plant.first.id$sp.lst[42])` is  ` Factor w/ 14 levels "['Artocarpus tamaran']",..: 13`

Comment: @Fino, the output is not "R" readable... `strsplit(as.vector(plant.first.id$sp.lst[42]),split = ",")[[1]][1]` gives `[1] "['Trema lamarckianum'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strplit` to remove the extra space and apostrophe

```
y <- sapply(x, gsub, pattern = "^\\['?|'?]$", replacement = "")
strsplit(y, "', '")

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "Ficus carica"              "Aphananthe philippinensis" "Ficus insipida"            "Aphananthe monoica"       
[5] "Castilla elastica"         "Maclura cochinchinensis"   "Maclura fruticosa"        

[[3]]
[1] "Artocarpus tamaran"
```